# SQL JOINS: I need to SELECT sold orders between 8 and 10 in AdventureWorks2016?

Tags: sql, join, adventureworks

So im in the middle of a school project, and im stuck on this task.
Im learning how to use joins, but i am seriously stuck on this task.
I need to select sold orders between 8 and 10 in AdventureWorks2016, in the table called
"Sales.SalesOrderDetail" Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please, paste details and code you did and you are stuck.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far and the table name and column details.  Ideally, if you have table data definition layout or structure.  If you are getting errors, those would help too.